# Definition of interior point

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

The definition of interior-point says "point $p$ in a set $S$ is interior point of $S$ if $\exists \delta \gt 0 : \mathcal B \left( p,\delta \right) \subseteq S  $ but then as the open Ball $\mathcal B \left( p,\delta \right)$ is entirely contained in S and open ball have always infinite number of points, can we say $\exists \delta \gt 0 : \mathcal B \left( p,\delta \right) \subsetneq S  \implies  \exists \frac{\delta}{2} \gt 0 : \left( \mathcal B \left( p,\frac{\delta}{2} \right) \subseteq \mathcal B \left( p,\delta \right) \right) \cup \left( limit \space points \space of \space \mathcal B \left( p,\frac{\delta}{2} \right) \subseteq \mathcal B \left( p,\delta \right) \right)   $

thus implying that thereis a closed ball containing $p$ . So will all interior points will have a closed ball containing it?

Comment: What spaces are you asking about? Normed spaces over an infinite field, or general metric spaces?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur I am thinking of finite dimensional metric spaces. But if possible please point out where it might fail (if it will) in infinite dimensional case.

Comment: @Keen-ameteur I am thinking of finite dimensional metric spaces. But if possible please point out where it might fail (if it will) in infinite dimensional case.

Comment: I should say first that I don't fully understand what your statement is. Do you want to give an equivalent condition for $p$ being an interior point?

Comment: Also the issue is not about the dimension of a metric space, which I think you mean dimension of a vector space. Given that a field is discrete and you have a finite dimensional vector space, your metric space is finite, and I think what you are trying to say won't work.

Comment: I think the answer is *yes*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General facts: $B(p,r) = \{x\mid d(x,y) < r\}$ is an open set in any metric space (any $r>0$). This justifies the name "open ball" (where open = every points is interior in the above sense).

$D(p,r)=\{ x\mid d(x,y) \le r\}$ is a closed set for any $r>0$, justifying the name *closed disk* for such a set. The proof of this is most easily done by noting that if $y \notin D(x,r)$: $$B(y,d(x,y) - r) \subseteq X\setminus D(x,r)$$ so that every point of $X\setminus D(x,r)$ is an interior point of it etc.

This indeed implies that if $x$ is an interior point of $S$ witnessed by $B(x,r)$ indeed $D(x,\frac{r}{2}) \subseteq B(x,r)$ shows that $x$ also has a closed disk neighbourhood sitting inside $S$.

From a general topology point of view this shows that $X$ in its metric topology is *regular* (it has local bases of closed sets). Of course, much more is true (such topologies are even perfectly normal).

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Suppose $\ x \in \overline{B\left(p,\frac{\delta}{2}\right)}.\ $

Then by definition of *closure of a set in a metric space*, $\ \exists\ \{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subseteq B\left(p,\frac{\delta}{2}\right)\ $ such that $\ x_n\to x,\ $ i.e. $\ d(x_n, x)\to 0.\ $ Thus we have:

$d(p,x)\leq d(p,x_n) + d(x_n,x) \leq \frac{\delta}{2} + d(x_n, x)\to \frac{\delta}{2}^+,\ $ therefore $\ d(p,x)\overset{*}{\leq} \frac{\delta}{2} < \delta.$

This shows that $\overline{B\left(p,\frac{\delta}{2}\right)} \subseteq B\left(p,\delta\right).$

$*\ $ In fact, $\ d(p,x) = \frac{\delta}{2},\ $ but showing this isn't required here.